# Creating a socket inside a thread spawned by a process

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

I am using python 3.8 and I am trying to connect to an mqtt broker. This connection follows the path below:

Client (spawned with multiprocessing) -> thread (spawned by the client) -> thread tries to connect

I see the threads getting stuck in the socket create_connection function when the socket is created. Curious enough, if I turn things around in this way:

Client (spawned with multithreading) -> process (spawned by the client) -> process tries to connect

it works. Is there any reason why in the first case threads can't create threads which will connect to the server? I can't really debug this as all the exception are swallowed by the process

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the process driving the threads and the threads themselves were all daemons. For some strange reason, even if you start the processes and the treads and you put a sleep after the process, threads won't connect to the server/broker even if they run. The solution is to not declare the threads as daemon and join them, then they will be capable to connect to the sever. The error wasn't clear at all because I would have expected the threads probably not to run up to that point or at least some clear indications of what was happening.